# IIS Manager crashes when adding a URLRewrite rule

Tags: iis

I am trying to add a URLRewrite blank rule to one of our servers, but when I select it and click OK to add it, IIS Manager closes abruptly.

I checked in the Event Log Viewer and there was an IISM crash with this message:

```
IISMANAGER_CRASH

IIS Manager terminated unexpectedly.

Exception:System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Microsoft.Web.Management.Server.WebManagementServiceException: Filename: \\?\C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config
Error: The configuration section 'webFarms' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

 ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Filename: \\?\C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config
Error: The configuration section 'webFarms' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration
```

Comment: The section `webFarms` comes with Web Farm Framework, https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-farm-framework (for IIS 10 and above, it merges in ARR), so when your machine does not have it installed, the exception is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like your config file is missing webfarms, section should be put directly under configuration node as the declaration in configSections.

Please double check if the section is configured at the correct place.